# How do I Validate a Key in ARGV?

Tags: c, cs50, argv, atoi, argc

I am so stuck. Been trying for days. I need to validate that each char input into `argv[1]` is a number but I have tried `isdigit`, `isalpha`, `char`, `atoi` conversion without any success. I'm still new at coding. I got frustrated and deleted everything to start over again but here's where I'm at now.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)        
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <strlen(argv[1]); k++)
        {
            printf("Success!\n");
            printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
        }    
    }     
    else                  
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }
}
```

Here is where I was at before. I kept getting a sanitization error everytime I tried to run this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (isdigit(argv[1]))
    {
        if(atoi(argv[1])) 
        {
            if (argc == 2)
            {         
                for (int x = 0; x < strlen(argv[1]); x++)
                {
                    printf("Success!\n");
                    printf("%s", argv[1]);
                }
            }        
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: /caesar key\n");
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `isdigit` only works for a single `char`.  You could loop through the entire string using `isdigit`.

Comment: Think of the order you do things... In the second example you check if there are arguments (i.e. `argv[1]` is valid) *after* you use that argument.

Comment: `if (isdigit(argv[1]))` is checking to see if an address is a `char` digit.

Comment: When you write "each char input into argv[1] is a number" do you mean that each character in argv[1] must be a digit ?

Comment: How might you write a function `int all_digits(char *s);` that looked at every character in the string and returned 1 (aka true) if all the characters are digits, and 0 (aka false) if not a digit?

Comment: @chmike Yes I want each char to be a number in order to receive the success printf.

Comment: @Steve Friedl I'll try that now. Not sure how to use char yet but I can do some reading.

Comment: if you have that function - which takes a pointer to a string - then you can call it with `argv[1]`, which is also a pointer to a string: `if (!all_digits(argv[i])) { ... not valid input }`

Comment: Hey everyone! I was able to get the code to evaluate the key for being positive or negative! It sees that if I add 5x that there is something wrong because of the x. However, it is now printing out the success printf AND the error. How can I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty example [on onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/BJVWKVaaS):

Didn't test a lot...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)        
    {
        int n = strlen(argv[1]);
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            if ( isdigit(argv[1][k]) )
            {
                printf("%c is a digit\n", argv[1][k]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c is not a digit\n", argv[1][k]);
            }
        }    
    }     
    else                  
    {
         printf("Error\n");
    }
}
```

Remember that `argv[1]` is a string, ie. an array of characters (with a null chracter at the end).

So you have to travel all the characters of this array.

EDIT: good comment from chmike in the other answer.

Comment: I see! So why do you add [k] to argv[1]? What does that do?

Comment: it means the element number k in the array argv[1]. for example if argv[1] = "123a", argv[1][0] = 1, argv[1][3] = a, etc...

Comment: Nitpick: `(char)0` is `NUL` and (probably) `(void *)0` is `NULL`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits, I didn't understand. The character 0 is coded as decimal value 48.

Comment: I don't mean `'0'`, I mean `0`.

Comment: Google `NUL vs NULL`.

Comment: I know what NUL and NULL are, but I don't understand the link with my example ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.  In your link, you use `"1A2"` as your string.  This is the same as `'1'` `'A'` `'2'` `0`.  `(char)'0' == 48` and `(char)0 == 0`.

Comment: yes you're right. But you don't evaluate the NUL character terminating the string due to strlen. strlen("1A2") = 3, not 4

Comment: Hey everyone! I was able to get the code to evaluate the key for being positive or negative! It sees that if I add 5x that there is something wrong because of the x. However, it is now printing out the success printf AND the error. How can I stop that from happening? –

Comment: "I was able to get the code to evaluate the key for being positive or negative" It doesn't make sense. You are analysing characters. Their decimal value (ascii code) is positive.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean So the program takes in user input and applies a key to the input. That key *must* be a number. If that key contains any letters, I need the program to print an error message prompting them to try again. So I need anything besides a number to trigger the error prompt.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Thank you so much man. I was able to get it and move on with the problem. I selected your answer as the top comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You had a good start with `for (int x = 0; x < strlen(argv[1]); x++)`, unfortunately it is not appropriate for C.

In C a string is terminated by the special character '\0'. The function `strlen` counts the characters from the start of the string to this special character. So when you write `for (int x = 0; x < strlen(argv[1]); x++)` is executes `strlen()` at each test of `x`.

Here is one way to avoid this:

```
 for (int x = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); x < n; x++)
```

This declares `i` initialized with 0, and `n` initialized with the length of argv[1]. The test compares `x` with `n` which is fast.

Another way to test if the end of the string is reached is to test if we reached that special character '\0'.

```
 for (int x = 0; argv[1][x] != '\0'; x++)
```

They are both equivalent. Make your pick.

Now, for each character you want to test if its a digit. You could use the function `isdigit()` that does the job for you. Or you could write the test yourself which is not that difficult.

```
for (int x = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); x < n; x++)
    if (!isdigit(argv[1][x])) {
        printf("failure: argv[1] is not all digits\n");
        return;
    }
printf("success: argv[1] is all digits\n")
```

The alternative test implemented ourselves is this

```
for (int x = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); x < n; x++)
    if (argv[1][x] < '0' || argv[1][x] > '9') {
        printf("failure: argv[1] is not all digits\n");
        return;
    }
printf("success: argv[1] is all digits\n")
```

Note that `argv[1][x]` contains the ASCII code of the character and that '0' is the ASCII code of 0. Note also that the ASCII code of digits is in the range '0' to '9' and this range contains only digits. This is why the test above test if `argv[1][x]` is not a digit.

Comment: Thanks! So with everyone's help I was able to get it to recognize positive and negative numbers however when i input 5x for example, it spits out the error msg which is good but then it also prints out a success message. Any thoughts why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some helper functions to check whether a string consists of all digits.

```
/* Return pointer to first non-digit character in a string. */
const char *findnondigit(const char *input)
{
    while (*input >= '0' && *input <= '9')
    {
        input++;
    }
    return input;
}

/* Return 1 if string is all digits, or 0 if it contains a non-digit. */
int checkalldigits(const char *input)
{
    /* Find first non-digit character in input. */
    input = findnondigit(input);
    /* Return whether first non-digit character is the string's null terminator. */
    return *input == '\0';
}
```

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if (checkalldigits(argv[1]))
        {
            printf("%s is all digits\n", argv[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is written in C. If you need to use the cs50 `string` type (which is really just a `char *`) then you can replace `const char *` with `string`. (The `const` just allows the function to work on read-only strings too, but is not essential. cs50 does not supply an exact equivalent of `const char *` but its nearest equivalent, `string`, will do in this case.)

Comment: Also, you can replace the test `*input >= '0' && *input <= '9'` with a simple `isdigit(*input)` if you want. Technically, `isdigit` isn't safe without an additional range check, but it should be fine for a cs50 level of expertise.

Comment: I was able to get it to recognize if an input is positive or negative but if I add a letter to the input such as 5x it gives me the error prompt which is good but it also gives me the success prompt. Any idea why that might happen?